# Are the changes from a Shifting Rune permanent, or do they revert if the rune is removed?

Tags: class-feature, pathfinder-2e

If I apply a [Shifting Rune](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=302) to a weapon, change the weapon into a different weapon type, and then remove the Shifting Rune, does it revert back to its original form?

Does this also apply to [Champions](https://2e.aonprd.com/Classes.aspx?ID=4) with the Blade Ally feature, which can give your weapon the effects of the Shifting Rune for a day?

Answer (score 1):

The Shifting Rune's activation lists no duration or conditions. The change is therefore permanent, even when you remove the rune.

Comment: This doesn't sound right to me but I can't find anything to refute it. Interesting RAW